# Internet Sharing despite 802.1X

Tags: network, wifi, internet-sharing

I have an ethernet network that authenticates with 802.1X. I want to provide temporary access to that network over WiFi, using my existing Hardware (MacBook Pro). I know about Internet Sharing in the System Preferences, but it denies sharing an 802.1X connection.

I am aware that doing so is less secure than the 802.1X connection, but I still need this temporary workaround. Windows and Linux make no big deal on that either.

Is it possible to bypass that security restriction on Mac? If not, what approach might let me share my internet manually? (e.g. on the terminal, not using that built-in feature) Any ideas are greatly appreciated ;)

Thanks in advance,
Lukas